# Linq to Entities - Project into object, search on all fields but only return ONE single property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, return-value, projection, entities

I'm curious if there is a way when using Linq to Entities to project into a new object, add .Where extensions to the initial Linq query (deferred execution and some building of dynamic lambda expressions) to further filter the query based on the properties of the projected object but (and here is the main question) ONLY return ONE property (say an ID field) from the database (the select statement generated only has one return value).

So I want to change the following:

```
        employees = from e in context.Employee
                    select new EmployeeObject()
                    {
                            EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
                            EmployeeFirstName = e.FirstName,
                             EmployeeLastName = e.LastName
                    };
```

So that I can append employees with .Where extensions with lambdas to further narrow the search but only return EmployeeId and have the SQL that is generated reflect that.

I'm still in the process of learning Linq to Entities so please forgive me if I did not describe something properly.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the formatting, Botz3000.  Just to reiterate what I commented below: The problem with this is I am unable to add subsequent .Where extensions along with lambdas that target other properties in the projected object/DTO because I get "The specified type member '<Member the Lambda was targetting>' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." which says to me you have to define the relationships for Linq to Entities (EF 4.1 by the way) in your projection in order for the subsequent .Where extensions to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var employeeIds = from e in context.Employee
                  select new {
                      EmployeeID = e.EmployeeId
                  };
```

It will only return the one property you need via an anonymous type. Or alternatively:

```
var employeeIds = context.Employee.Where(/*filters...*/).Select(e => e.EmployeeId);
// another alternative: 
var employeeIds = from e in context.Employee select e.EmployeeId;
```

That will give you just the Ids.

**EDIT**:
As long as you don't enumerate over the query, the query is not executed.
So if you say

```
var query = context.Employee;
```

you have a very simple query that you can decorate with additional clauses as much as you like:

```
query = query.Where(e => e.LastName.StartsWith("S"));
query = query.Where(e => e.FirstName == "Blah");
```

All those additions are not executing the query, so as long as your ObjectContext is valid, you can refine your query like that.

When you're done adding the clauses, you can add the final projection

```
var results = query.Select(e => e.EmployeeId);
```

and only then you should enumerate over `results` or use it somewhere. Of course you can only add the projection *after* you have performed your filtering, because per definition the projection just drops all properties other than EmployeeId.

Comment: I appreciate your time and assistance.  The problem with this is I am unable to add subsequent .Where extensions along with lambdas that target other properties in the projected object/DTO because I get this error "The specified type member '<Member the Lambda was targetting>' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." which says to me you have to define the relationships for Linq to Entities (EF 4.1 by the way) in your projection in order for the subsequent .Where extensions to work.

Comment: If I do that, the SQL that is generated returns everything and I can't seem to get it to search on all but only return the Id.  I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here...thanks!

Comment: @Wrasse If i understand correctly, you are trying to further filter the results **after** you have selected only the ID? That wouldn't work due to the type of the query results. You would have to wait with the actual selection until you have added all `where` clauses.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to find a way to set up the Linq query like the one above then, like you've stated, further filter the query with .Where(lambda) extension methods (iterating through a list of filters and applying them) and then, somehow, add a statement that tells EF to only return the employeeId (I hope that makes sense). That is...without having to resort to Linq to Objects after the full chunk of data is in memory after the database call.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: I know this is a bit complicated and I may be confusing the matter but the lambda expressions I'm applying based on the filters are strongly typed employee object lambdas and it seems that you cannot project onto the employy object, generate lambdas of that type to further filter the query but then only request that one property of that type is returned.

Comment: @Wrasse See my latest edit. I have used the technique described there in my earlier EF projects, too. It worked quite well for applying several filters before executing a query.

Comment: I ended up using something similar so I'm marking this as the answer and resolved.  What I did was apply all of the where extensions as you mentioned and then created a separate employee object (essentially separating the database and business objects to account for what needed to be done - there may be duplicate properties but this should make things a bit cleaner).  Then I selected into a new employee business object (since you could not include two projections into the same object in EF) just the employee Ids and everything is working well.  Thank you again for your time and attention!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand, but couldn't you do:

```
context.Employee.Where(x => x.FirstName = "Bob").Select(x => x.Id);
```